# Cancel notification when app is removed from recents(memory) list

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am using a service which shows an ongoing notification. when the app gets closed normally, notification disappears. But, if the user removed it from recent list app is closing and stops the service. But, the notification still appears. It is not a good user experience.

Note: I tried with onTaskRemoved() but it's not at all called.

How can I remove notification when app removed from recent list.

**Update:**
I have noticed the following 3 lines are called when the app is removed from recents or killed from other apps.

```
11-27 11:44:05.097 3916-4157/? D/StatusBar: onNotificationRemoved:  Key: 
0|com.example.player|888|null|10525


11-27 11:44:05.107 3916-3916/? D/PhoneStatusBar: removeNotification key=android.os.Binder@2e604ccc keyCode=778063052 old=StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.example.player user=UserHandle{0} id=888 tag=null score=0 key=0|com.example.player|888|null|10525: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.example.player/0x109008a vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 color=0xff40444a category=service actions=3 vis=PUBLIC))


11-27 11:44:05.137 4759-4759/? I/Launcher.ApplicationsMessage: update com.example.player/ to null
```

But, in my app, these 3 lines called when app killed not on removed from recents. I guess this may be a problem(I am missing something).

Comment: Clear the notification in `onDestroy()` of whatever `Activity` it is that appears in the recents list. An ongoing notification usually implies a service though, which doesn't necessarily end when an `Activity` is dismissed.

Comment: onDestroy() is not called when app removed from recents list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution.

I missed starting foreground service while building notification.

added these two lines and notification removed automatically when app removed from recent list / killed.

onBuildNotification():

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

onRemovenotification():

```
 stopForeground(true);
```

Comment: How to run these code when your app is killed. As far as I know, onDestroy() cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to cancel a Notification:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

In this code there is always the same id used for notifications. If you have different notifications that need to be cancelled and you have to save the ids that you used to create the Notification.

Comment: I've only one notification. and I didn't ask help to remove the notification.  I am in need to remove notification when the app is removed from the recent list which is user swiped to close the app. no methods getting called. and notification is not closing.

Comment: It happens when you have shown notification as foreground inside intent service. So  you must clear notification when you kill the service.