# How to remove/delete all notification when an android app is killed?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I wanted to delete all my app notification when application killed. I am not using service. So, I can not use [onTaskRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29) and I have tried using OnDestroy method to [CancelAll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancelAll()) notifications. But OnDestroy is not being called when I kill application from task.

Does it possible to clear notification without using service?

Comment: Here is a similar issue that maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052033/cancel-notification-when-app-is-removed-from-recentsmemory-list .

Comment: Thanks for the reference @LucasZhang-MSFT. Provided link using service. I wanted to clear all notification without service. Does it possible?

Comment: @Ranjit Have you found out your solution?

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan, Solutions are available with service implementation. If you can use service then check this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel